# Не обновляется собственное View при изменении полей класса

Tags: android, kotlin, customview, android-customview

Написал собственно View. HexaView наследует класс View. Туда добавлены поля:

```
var angle_cren: Float = 15f
var angle_tang: Float = 10f
var angle_risk: Float = 225f
```

Также есть две кнопки.
Также в MainActivity написаны обработчики нажатий на кнопки(onClickTakeOff, onClickLanding), которые меняют поля angle_cren, angle_tang, angle_risk. Поиск HexaView происходит по id.
Проблема заключается в том, что при нажатии на кнопку, значения этих полей меняются, но при этом HexaView не перерисовывается на самом экране. В чем может быть проблема? Как обновить HexaView на экране с новыми параметрами?
Код:
MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.hexacopterapp

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.SystemClock
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.hexacopterapp.view.HexaView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun onClickTakeOff(view : View) {
        val HView = findViewById<HexaView>(R.id.hexaView)
        HView.angle_cren = 155f
        HView.angle_tang = 15f
        HView.angle_risk = 30f
        Log.d("MyLog", txt.text.toString())
        Log.d("MyLog", HView.angle_cren.toString())
    }

    fun onClickLanding(view : View) {
        val HView = findViewById<HexaView>(R.id.hexaView)
        HView.angle_cren = -25f
        HView.angle_tang = -15f
        HView.angle_risk = -125f
        Log.d("MyLog", HView.angle_cren.toString())
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
}
```

HexaView.kt:

```
package com.example.hexacopterapp.view

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import androidx.annotation.Nullable


class HexaView : View {
    private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private val paint_text = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    var angle_cren: Float = 15f
    var angle_tang: Float = 10f
    var angle_risk: Float = 225f
    val a = 1

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {}
    constructor(context: Context?, @Nullable attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {}
    constructor(context: Context?, @Nullable attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    ) {
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.save()

        var width = width.toFloat()
        var height = height.toFloat()


        canvas.scale(.5f * width, -1f * height)
        canvas.translate(1f, -1f)
        paint.color = Color.parseColor("#17C3E1")
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        canvas.drawRect(-1f, 0.5f, 1f, 1f, paint)
        paint.color = Color.parseColor("#FF7CFF46")
        canvas.drawRect(-1f, 0f, 1f, 0.5f, paint)

        paint.color = Color.WHITE
        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        paint.strokeWidth = 0.005f
        //Шкала для угла крена
        val maxValue = 150
        val value = 25
        val scale = 0.97f
        val step = Math.PI / 180
        for (i in 30..maxValue) {
            val x1 = Math.cos(step * i).toFloat() * 0.5f
            val y1 = Math.sin(step * i).toFloat() * 0.5f
            var x2: Float
            var y2: Float
            if (i % 10 == 0) {
                x2 = x1 * scale * 0.98f * 0.99f
                y2 = y1 * scale * 0.98f * 0.99f
            } else {
                x2 = x1 * scale * 0.99f
                y2 = y1 * scale * 0.99f
            }
            canvas.drawLine(x1, (y1 + 0.5f), x2, (y2 + 0.5f), paint)
        }
        //Шкала для угла рысканья
        for (i in 0..360) {
            val x1 = Math.cos(step * i).toFloat() * 0.15f
            val y1 = Math.sin(step * i).toFloat() * 0.15f
            var x2: Float
            var y2: Float
            if (i % 45 == 0){
                x2 = x1 * scale * 0.95f * 0.99f
                y2 = y1 * scale * 0.95f * 0.99f
            } else if (i % 10 == 0) {
                x2 = x1 * scale * 0.98f * 0.99f
                y2 = y1 * scale * 0.98f * 0.99f
            } else {
                x2 = x1 * scale * 0.99f
                y2 = y1 * scale * 0.99f
            }
            canvas.drawLine((x1 + 0.75f), (y1 + 0.75f), (x2 + 0.75f), (y2 + 0.75f), paint)
        }
        paint.strokeWidth = 0.0025f
        canvas.drawLine(0.75f, 0.6f, 0.75f, 0.9f, paint)
        canvas.drawLine(0.6f, 0.75f, 0.9f, 0.75f, paint)

        //Шкала для угла тангажа
        paint.color = Color.WHITE
        paint.strokeWidth = 0.005f
        canvas.drawLine(-0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, paint)
        canvas.drawLine(-0.05f, 0.2f, 0.05f, 0.2f, paint)
        canvas.drawLine(-0.1f, 0.3f, 0.1f, 0.3f, paint)
        canvas.drawLine(-0.05f, 0.4f, 0.05f, 0.4f, paint)
        canvas.drawLine(-0.1f, 0.5f, 0.1f, 0.5f, paint)
        canvas.drawLine(-0.05f, 0.6f, 0.05f, 0.6f, paint)
        canvas.drawLine(-0.1f, 0.7f, 0.1f, 0.7f, paint)
        canvas.drawLine(-0.05f, 0.8f, 0.05f, 0.8f, paint)
        canvas.drawLine(-0.1f, 0.9f, 0.1f, 0.9f, paint)

        //Указатель курса и угла тангажа
        paint.color = Color.RED
        paint.strokeWidth = 0.005f
        var h: Float = 0.2f / 10
        if (angle_tang > 20f) {
            angle_tang = 20f
        }
        canvas.drawLine(Math.cos(step * angle_cren).toFloat() * 0.45f, Math.sin(step * angle_cren).toFloat() * 0.45f + 0.5f + (h * angle_tang), Math.cos(step * angle_cren).toFloat() * 0.2f, Math.sin(step * angle_cren).toFloat() * 0.2f + 0.5f + (h * angle_tang), paint)
        canvas.drawLine(Math.cos(step * angle_cren).toFloat() * -0.45f, Math.sin(step * angle_cren).toFloat() * -0.45f + 0.5f + (h * angle_tang), Math.cos(step * angle_cren).toFloat() * -0.2f, Math.sin(step * angle_cren).toFloat() * -0.2f + 0.5f + (h * angle_tang), paint)
        canvas.drawLine(Math.cos(step * (angle_cren - 30)).toFloat() * 0.11f, Math.sin(step * (angle_cren - 30)).toFloat() * 0.11f + 0.5f + (h * angle_tang), 0f, 0.5f + (h * angle_tang), paint)
        canvas.drawLine(Math.cos(step * (angle_cren + 30)).toFloat() * -0.11f, Math.sin(step * (angle_cren + 30)).toFloat() * -0.11f + 0.5f + (h * angle_tang), 0f, 0.5f + (h * angle_tang), paint)
        paint.strokeWidth = 0.005f

        //Указатель угла крена
        canvas.drawLine(Math.cos(step * (angle_cren + 90f)).toFloat() * 0.4851f, Math.sin(step * (angle_cren + 90f)).toFloat() * 0.4851f + 0.5f, Math.cos(step * (angle_cren + 90f + 3f)).toFloat() * 0.4851f * 0.93f, Math.sin(step * (angle_cren + 90f + 3f)).toFloat() * 0.4851f * 0.93f + 0.5f, paint)
        canvas.drawLine(Math.cos(step * (angle_cren + 90f)).toFloat() * 0.4851f, Math.sin(step * (angle_cren + 90f)).toFloat() * 0.4851f + 0.5f, Math.cos(step * (angle_cren + 90f - 3f)).toFloat() * 0.4851f * 0.93f, Math.sin(step * (angle_cren + 90f - 3f)).toFloat() * 0.4851f * 0.93f + 0.5f, paint)
        canvas.drawLine(Math.cos(step * (angle_cren + 90f + 3f)).toFloat() * 0.4851f * 0.93f, Math.sin(step * (angle_cren + 90f + 3f)).toFloat() * 0.4851f * 0.93f + 0.5f, Math.cos(step * (angle_cren + 90f - 3f)).toFloat() * 0.4851f * 0.93f, Math.sin(step * (angle_cren + 90f - 3f)).toFloat() * 0.4851f * 0.93f + 0.5f, paint)

        //Указатель угла рысканья
        paint.strokeWidth = 0.0025f

        canvas.drawLine(Math.cos(step * angle_risk).toFloat() * -0.01f + 0.75f, Math.sin(step * angle_risk).toFloat() * 0.01f + 0.75f, Math.cos(step * angle_risk).toFloat() * 0.01f + 0.75f,Math.sin(step * angle_risk).toFloat() * -0.01f + 0.75f, paint)
        canvas.drawLine(Math.cos(step * angle_risk).toFloat() * -0.01f + 0.75f, Math.sin(step * angle_risk).toFloat() * 0.01f + 0.75f, Math.cos(step * (angle_risk - 90)).toFloat() * 0.15f + 0.75f,Math.sin(step * (angle_risk + 90)).toFloat() * 0.15f + 0.75f, paint)
        canvas.drawLine(Math.cos(step * angle_risk).toFloat() * 0.01f + 0.75f,Math.sin(step * angle_risk).toFloat() * -0.01f + 0.75f, Math.cos(step * (angle_risk - 90)).toFloat() * 0.15f + 0.75f,Math.sin(step * (angle_risk + 90)).toFloat() * 0.15f + 0.75f, paint)

        canvas.save()
        canvas.rotate(90 - 180.toFloat() * (value / maxValue.toFloat()))
        canvas.restore()
        canvas.restore()
    }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.example.hexacopterapp.view.HexaView
        android:id="@+id/hexaView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.434"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.45"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.105" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-20"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.45"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.896" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.467"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.45"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.313" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-10"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.45"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.684" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.037" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.427"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.066" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.573"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.066" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.393"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.096" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.608"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.096" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="50"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.327"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.211" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="50"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.673"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.211" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="40"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.359"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.145" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="40"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.641"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.145" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="45"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.955"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.114" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="135"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.966"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.362" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="В"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.968"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.234" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView22"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="315"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.807"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.114" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView23"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="С"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.879"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.048" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView26"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ю"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.884"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.428" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="З"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.789"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.234" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="225"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.807"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.362" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="81dp"
        android:onClick="onClickLanding"
        android:text="Landing"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.972"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.951" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="81dp"
        android:onClick="onClickTakeOff"
        android:text="Take Off"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.027"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.951" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="60"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.302"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.283" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="60"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.698"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.283" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно явно запустить перерисовку вызовом метода invalidate